# Log client browse website information in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using this code to get client information :

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",function (data) {
        console.log(data.geoplugin_request);
        console.log(data.geoplugin_countryName);
 });
```

Then I would like to record this information at the first time that client visit the website (session start of the website). My current project  are using backbone.js, require.js, underscore.js.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have application.js file which act as a entry point of the backbone aplication which initializes your router an all stuff, you can set the client details in the browser using localStorage.

```
// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedVar = localStorage.getItem('countryName');
if( retrievedVar == null) {
      $.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",function (data) {
           console.log(data.geoplugin_countryName);
               // Put the object into storage
           localStorage.seItem('countryName', JSON.stringify(data.geoplugin_countryName)
 });
```

Hence the getJSON will only be fired once when localStorage var is not set.

Comment: No application.js in my project.

Comment: From where do you initialize your router?

Comment: Sorry my bad, there's `app.js`, then I did this : `var initialize = function(){ //log client info here } return initialize: initialize};` But the `logClientInfo` function always run when I refreshing webpage.

Comment: Yaa..you are right..that's why you'll use localStorage..see my updated answer.

Comment: I want to record it in database not localStorage.

Comment: I was logging it in asp.net mvc by `Global.asax`, it will awsome if backbone had it.